# Как можно усовершенстовать данный код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, карты

Работаю над интересным проектом. Возможность строить маршрут по рисунку.

Но возникла проблема.

Нормальный маршрут строиться только с одной картинкой. Не могу придумать как усовершенствовать код так, чтобы работало и с другими картинками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Пример не совпадения силуэта картинки и построения маршрута]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
import folium

#Data Sanalytics
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# Spatial Data
import geopandas as gpd
import geojson
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import flexpolyline


img = cv2.imread('cat.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 70, 0.0001, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

squeezed = corners.squeeze().tolist()

x_squeezed = np.array([i[0] for i in squeezed])
y_squeezed = np.array([i[1] for i in squeezed])



def distance(P1, P2):
    """
    This function computes the distance between 2 points defined by
     P1 = (x1,y1) and P2 = (x2,y2)
    """
    return ((P1[0] - P2[0])**2 + (P1[1] - P2[1])**2) ** 0.5


def optimized_path(coords, start=None):
    """
    This function finds the nearest point to a point
    coords should be a list in this format coords = [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2] , ...]
    """
    if start is None:
        start = coords[0]
    pass_by = coords
    path = [start]
    pass_by.remove(start)
    while pass_by:
        nearest = min(pass_by, key=lambda x: distance(path[-1], x))
        path.append(nearest)
        pass_by.remove(nearest)
    return path

path = optimized_path(squeezed)
print(path)
x = np.array([i[0] for i in path])
y = np.array([i[1] for i in path])

matrix = np.array([x, -y])

plt.plot(matrix[0], matrix[1], marker='o')
for index, coord in enumerate(matrix[0]):
    plt.text(coord, matrix[1][index], str(index))

plt.show()
###################################################


meters = 75

# Координаты в системе координат EPSG:3857
x_orx_original_point = 4173551.0
y_original_point = 7529089.9

mx = x * meters + x_orx_original_point
my = y * -meters + y_original_point

mxy = list(zip(mx,my))

picture_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {'id': range(0, len(mxy))},
    crs="EPSG:3857",
    geometry=[Point(resu) for resu in mxy]
)

picture_df['geometry'] = picture_df['geometry'].to_crs(epsg=4326)

picture_df.to_file("cat.geojson", driver='GeoJSON', encoding="utf-8")

SERVICE = 'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=yr2XtTdR-eft68m7njtNMPYTxXfjo72ajsr_2phZ-dM&transportMode=pedestrian&return=polyline'

file = open('cat.geojson')
data = geojson.load(file).copy()
file.close()

coords_list = [feature['geometry']['coordinates'] for feature in data['features']]

start_point = coords_list[0]
destination_point = coords_list[len(coords_list) -1]

coords_list.remove(start_point)
coords_list.remove(destination_point)

origin = f'&origin={start_point[1]},{start_point[0]}'
destination = f'&destination={destination_point[1]},{destination_point[0]}&'
waypoints = '&'.join([f'via={coords[1]},{coords[0]}' for coords in coords_list])

routes = requests.get(SERVICE + origin + destination + waypoints).json()
print(len(routes))
print(routes)
def decode (section):
    line = flexpolyline.decode(section['polyline'])
    line = [(coord[1], coord[0])  for coord in line]
    return LineString(line)

geometry = [ decode(section) for section in routes['routes'][0]['sections']]

route_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geometry)

route_df.to_file("route.geojson", driver='GeoJSON', encoding="utf-8")

m = folium.Map(
        location=[55.846683487402089, 37.501707654705264],
        zoom_start=15,
        tiles='https://1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/reduced.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png?lg=RU&apiKey=yr2XtTdR-eft68m7njtNMPYTxXfjo72ajsr_2phZ-dM',
        attr='HERE'
    )

folium.GeoJson('cat.geojson', name="geojson").add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson('route.geojson', name="geojson").add_to(m)

m.save('map.html')
```

Comment: Что значит "Нормальный маршрут строится только с одной картинкой"? Какая проблема с другими картинками?

Comment: силуэт картинки и сам маршрут не совпадают

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример этого несовпадения.

Comment: добавил картинку